# subtract time from current date [ bash - HP-UX ]

Tags: bash, hp-ux

I would like to know how to subtract X minutes from the current system date. 
I do know how to subtract hours, but I need a more flexible solution.

```
NEWDATE=`TZ=GMT-1 date +%y%m%d%H%M.%S` 
echo $NEWDATE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# date
Tue Aug  7 17:11:01 BST 2012

# date -d "-10 minutes"
Tue Aug  7 17:01:01 BST 2012

# date -d "-10 minutes +30 seconds"
Tue Aug  7 17:01:31 BST 2012
```

But based on the man page, `-d` is not available on HP-UX. Try this one:

```
perl -e 'use POSIX;print strftime "%Y%m%d %H%M.%S\n",localtime time-(30*60);'
```

Comment: Will HP-UX's date work with those date strings? I thought those were extensions on GNU date.

Comment: #$^&!.. sorry.. missed the tag! @Simone Di Cola: what tools are available there? perl? awk?

Comment: @Simone Di Cola: well, it still depends on the version your hp-ux uses. does that perl code work? `perl --version`, `awk --version`?

Comment: [root@HUG30093 /] # perl --version

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for IA64.ARCHREV_0-thread-multi
(with 13 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: [root@HUG30093 /] # awk --version
Usage: awk [-F fs][-v Assignment][-f Progfile|Program][Assignment|File] ...
[root@HUG30093 /] # which awk    
/usr/bin/awk